# Get MSN messenger buddy icon image files

Tags: images, windows-live-messenger

Is it possible to access the raw image files for buddy icons in MSN messenger, somewhere on the file system?  I have a buddy icon that I would like to use somewhere else, but I'm not sure how to get the actual file.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly aMSN (http://www.amsn-project.net/) enables you to use others msn icons

Comment: OP wanted to take out the existing images not add new i guess